# Jquery UI Auto Complete - CodeIgniter - CSRF + Models + Controllers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, codeigniter

> **Updated answer with help from hackre, christian.thomas, olimortimer :**

The problem : I wasn't filtering.

So how I solved it :

Jquery :

```
$(function() {
  var cct = $.cookie('ccn');
    $( "#searchscholarship" ).autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/global/c_ajax/ajax_scholarshipNames',
          type: "post",
          data: {term: request.term, 'ctn': cct},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            response( $.map( data.myData, function( item ) {
              return {
                label: item.scholName,
                value: item.scholID
              }
            }));
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 3,
    });
  });
```

Big issue with AJAX and CI was the CSRF component, had to do some google searching on the "accepted" method of sending the token.

Then that sends to my c_ajax controller :

```
public function ajax_scholarshipNames() 
    {
        $this -> load -> model('m_ajax');
        $post = $this -> input -> post();
        $data = $this -> m_ajax -> scholarships($post);
        foreach ($data as $d) {
            $value['myData'][] = array(
                'scholID' => $d["intScholarshipID"],
                'scholName' => $d["txtScholarshipName"]
            );
        }
        $this -> output -> set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($value);
    }
```

Then in the model :

```
public function scholarships($post) // I usually don't use model just for database transactions but in this use case thats all I need the model to do. 
    {
        $name = '%' . $post["term"] . '%';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tableScholarship WHERE txtScholarshipName LIKE :name";
        $ajax_schol = $this -> db -> conn_id -> prepare($sql);
        $ajax_schol -> bindParam(":name", $name);
        $ajax_schol -> execute();

        return $ajax_schol -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Again thank you!

> **ORIGINAL POST**

I am trying to set up auto complete and for the most part I've done just fine, except now I am trying to tweak the remaining few issues with it.

Currently what is bothering me is that when I type for example "Scholarship" (which is a fake name of a scholarship in my DB) "fewfew" also appear (which is another name)

If I type S alone Scholarship should be the only thing that shows not "fewfew"

My Jquery :

```
$(function() { 
    $( "#searchscholarship" ).autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/global/c_ajax_controller/ajax_scholarshipNames',
          data: {term: request.term},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            response( $.map( data.myData, function( item ) {
              return {
                label: item.scholName, // Here it will either be Scholarship or fewfew
                value: item.scholID // 8 or 9
              }
            }));
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 1,
    });
  });
```

my Php function in the ajax controller :

```
public function ajax_scholarshipNames() 
    {
        $data = $this -> m_global -> db_data($where = array(), $table = "tableScholarship");

        foreach ($data as $d) {
            $value['myData'][] = array(
                'scholID' => $d["intScholarshipID"],
                'scholName' => $d["txtScholarshipName"]
            );
        }
        $this -> output -> set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($value);        
    }
```

If it helps I am also using Codeigniter with CSRF turned ON however it doesn't seem to be affecting the outcome since the form I am using is using form_open :

```
<div id="editscholarship">
  <?php
    if (!$this -> session -> userdata('scholarshipID')) {
        echo form_open('/global/c_scholarshipmaintance/editscholarship/' . urlencode('1'));
        echo 'Please Enter Scholarship Name Below : <br>' . form_input('findScholarship', '', 'autocomplete="off", id="searchscholarship"');
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time.

Edit :

A picture of the respone(s) I am getting

[image]

Comment: If all is fine all is fine. Software does only what it has been written into. So how should we tell you what you did wrong?

Comment: Very good point @hakre. Not all is fine =\

Comment: Where are you passing in 'term' into the CI Model to filter? You're passing in $where, but that's a blank array?

Comment: Ah... I see what your saying =/ ... I'm going to update my code.

Comment: Hint: Rewrite a test-example from scratch. Try to do as little as possible to demonstrate the error. This most often alone points one in the right direction.

Comment: Updated my OP, thanks a lot hackre and christian :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're filtering the values that are coming back, as you're missing the options in your jQuery Ajax function which tells it what to filter on.

See the example here - http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

```
      data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 12,
        name_startsWith: request.term
      },
```

However, I prefer to send the query to the PHP controller, and filter the values whilst running it against the database.  This way, you're only sending back the values you require, and not all values *and then* filtering.